# What meaning does "for" have in the phrase "reputation for"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, prepositions, for

examples with "*reputation for*" from [oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/reputation):
**(1)**  *The company enjoys an international reputation **for** quality of design*.
**(2)** *a politician with a reputation **for** honesty*
**(3)** *I'm aware of Mark's reputation **for** being late.*

What meaning does "*for*" have in the phrase "*reputation for*"?
Could you show me please in a dictionary that meaning of "*for*" which the examples above would be appropriate for?

Comment: Note that sometimes it's a bad idea to split up phrasals and try to pin down a meaning for each of the component words; rather, they have a meaning together. It's enough to say that "'reputation' pairs with 'for' in the construction 'have a reputation for something.'" There are other constructions too; it can often pair with "as" like "a reputation as a shrewd dealer."

Comment: It's the grammatised use of "for". Its role is not to express spacial relations as preposition often do but to mark a grammatical function. The preposition is specified by the head, i.e. "reputation". You can look it up in any good dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

[Merriam-Webster "for" (preposition) sense 1c](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for) "used as a function word to indicate the object or recipient of a perception, desire, or activity".

When you have a reputation it has an object: you have a certain reputation with regards to something. This is expressed either as a proposition with "that" ("He has the reputation that whenever there's a fire alarm he panics and runs out screaming") or as a noun phrase following the preposition "for" ("He has a reputation for panicking"). "For" is used to link the object to the word "reputation".

It doesn't have a meaning separable from its use here. You can't just translate a preposition into other prepositions; if you could, we wouldn't need all the prepositions.

Comment: Maybe you're right. Though the phrase "_used as a function word to indicate the object or recipient of a perception, desire, or activity_" is, in my opinion, very unclear for understanding and, therefore, very bad for using in dictionaries.

Answer (score -1):

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/for) has

> **for** *preposition* (**BECAUSE OF**)
> because of or as a result of something:
>
> *I'm feeling all the better for my holiday.*
> *She did 15 years in prison for murder.*

Looking at your second quotation

> a politician with a reputation for honesty

This means

> has a good reputation because they are honest

Comment: When a dictionary says "_for_" means "_because of_" in the sentence "_She did 15 years in prison **for** murder_", that means "_She did 15 years in prison **because of** murder_" is a similar sentence. But if we replace "_for_" with "_because of_" in "_a politician with a reputation **for** honesty_", we get "_a politician with a reputation **because of** honesty_" which looks very strange — therefore, "_for_" does not mean "_because of_" here.

Comment: The definition says "because of **or as a result of** something".

Comment: Did I understand you correctly that "_a politician with a reputation **for** honesty_" means "_a politician with a reputation **as a result of** honesty_"?

Comment: @Lovii A defintion attempts to get at the meaning of a word in a succinct manner. It doesn't provide alternative phrases that can be *substituted* for the word in a sentence.  The definition is not  a syntactic "component".  **for** can also be glossed "in respect to".

Comment: . A politician who has a reputation for honesty is one people believe they can depend on to speak the truth.  The politician is known to be a person who speaks the truth.  The politician is reputed to be honest.

Comment: An automobile manufacturer can have a reputation for unreliability.  So it's not necessarily a good reputation. Their repute is in respect to, or founded on, a particular quality, character, or characteristic they are thought to have.

Comment: **In regards to** is close in meaning here.

Comment: You just have to accept that a certain preposition is 'the one we use in a particular context' without necessarily being able to define it exactly.

Comment: This isn't really the exact definition, but that's because it doesn't always make sense to view a preposition in terms of a definition. The preposition is used in this context to connect two words to form a certain meaning. Which preposition you use depends on the relationship between the two words. (For comparison, try and explain what "have" means in "I have baked a cake".)

Answer (score -2):

Think of "for" as a shorter or more direct form of "because of".